# Android data stored in sd card

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sdcard

I have created database which is stored in sd card. But it seems something is wrong happened. 
Here is code createDatabase

```
public void createDatabase(){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/smsgarbage.db";
    sqlite = openOrCreateDatabase(path, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    try {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE tblGarbage(id text PRIMARY KEY, prefixNum text)";
        sqlite.execSQL(query);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oncreate dabase was created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In manifest file, I have filled:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

SomeOne who is master about this issue, please take time check it out again to support me. I appreciate about that.

Comment: `something is wrong happened` ... post the error log. Then only the issue can be found.

Comment: What wrong happened?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to create the database over the sdcard the correct way to implement see the below way let me know if you have any query if you did not get  me at any points.

Step 1. Extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` replace the database name with your full sd card path. This will create the database over the define location.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


import com.adb.test.sql.DAO.FoodMarchantDAO;


public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "smsgarbage.db";

    private static final String DATABASE_PATH_NAME = getDBAbsolutePath();

    /**
     * Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. This method always returns very quickly. 
     * The database is not actually created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase()
     * or getReadableDatabase() is called.
     * @param context
     * @param name
     * @param factory
     * @param version
     */
    public SQLite(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_PATH_NAME, null, version);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // when we call SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() this would called
        // In fist time application install if no database then it would called once but that time Application 
        // database might be null we have to used here db
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
    }

    private static String getDBAbsolutePath() {
        return new StringBuilder().append(appHomeDirectory()).append(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
    }

    public static String appHomeDirectory() {
        return new StringBuilder().append(getExternalStoragePath()).append("foodbazer").append("/").toString();
    }
}
```

Step 2. At application level how to access the SQLite help class see the below.

```
import com.adb.test.sql.data.SQLite;
import android.app.Application;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class FoodBazerApplication extends Application{

    private static FoodBazerApplication mFoodBazerApplication;

    public SQLiteDatabase mAppLevelDB;

    public static FoodBazerApplication getInstance()
    {
        return mFoodBazerApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mFoodBazerApplication = this;
        SQLite tmpSQL= new SQLite(getApplicationContext());
        // it return null if first time database create onCreate() called,
        // once database create it will open the database so openDataBase() called
        mAppLevelDB = tmpSQL.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```